# specify matplotlibrc file path in python script

Tags: python, matplotlib

After some research in the matplotlib documentation I could not find the answer to my question so here it goes.

Is it possible to give the (relative or absolute) path to the matplotlibrc file I want to use? I have different configuration for different type of plot and I would like use them without copy/paste to the working directory each time...

Thank you!

Comment: This seems like a strange question to ask, as simply trying it out would have caused less work than asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/users/style_sheets.html) states:

> You can create custom styles and use them by **calling `style.use` with the path or URL to the style sheet**. Alternatively, if you add your .mplstyle file to mpl_configdir/stylelib, you can reuse your custom style sheet with a call to style.use().

So, yes, it is possible.